# A question about switching the order of $\int$ and $\lim$ for a series of complex functions

Tags: calculus, integration, complex-analysis, limits, measure-theory

When I took undergraduate complex analysis, the instructor was trying to prove an inequality, and he used a technique as below:

$$\int \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} f_n dz= \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \int f_n dz \cdots (*)$$

And he claimed that we can use this, because all $f_n$s are measurable and $f_n$ converges uniformly to some complex function $f$.

Can someone help to explain why from measurability and uniform convergence of $f_n$s we have $(*)$, or show me theorems that I need to study deeply? Thanks!

Comment: Integral over what? If it is over  a path $\gamma$ then the equality follows as in the case of intergals over any finite measure space.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As geetha290krm points out, there are details that are missing that are important. Here is my stab at a version of this that you might see in an undergraduate complex analysis course, but in any case you should edit your question to add these details for posterity's sake.

**Proposition.** Let $\gamma:[0,1] \to \mathbb C$ be a smooth, rectifiable contour of length $\ell$ and $\{f_n(z)\}_{n = 1}^\infty$ be a sequence of measurable functions which are integrable on $\gamma$. Furthermore, suppose that there exists a measurable function $f(z)$ which is integrable on $\gamma$ such that  $$\lim_{n \to \infty}f_n(z) = f(z)$$ uniformly on $\gamma$, then $$ \lim_{n \to \infty} \int_\gamma f_n(z) \mathrm d z = \int_\gamma f(z) \mathrm d z.$$

*Proof.* Uniform convergence means: $\forall \epsilon >0$ $\exists N>0$ such that for all $n>N$ and for all $z \in \gamma$, $$|f_n(z) - f(z)| < \frac{\epsilon}{\ell}.$$ Taking $n>N$ and using the triangle inequality we have $$\left| \int_\gamma f_n(z) \mathrm d z - \int_\gamma f(z) \mathrm d z \right| \leq \int_\gamma |f_n(z) - f(z)| |\mathrm d z| < \frac{\epsilon}{\ell} \int_\gamma |\mathrm d z| = \epsilon.$$